# Custom object collection unable to cast to list

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, collections, generic-collections

I have a custom object

```
Public Class oPerson
private properties
...
public properties
...
End Class
```

Then I have a collection of oPersons (oPeople):

```
Public Class oPeople
    Inherits Generic.List(Of oPerson)
End Class
```

Has worked well for years, but now that I want to use some collection functions with the oPeople such as:

```
oPeople.Take(5)
```

I receive this error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[BusinessLayer.DataContainer.oPerson]' to type 'BusinessLayer.DataContainer.oPeople'.

Other than changing my code from:

```
Dim students As BusinessLayer.DataContainer.oPeople = GetStudents()
```

to:

```
Dim students as List(Of BusinessLayer.DataContainer.oPerson) = GetStudents()
```

I'd like to keep my oPeople class.

Comment: What do you try to do with the result of `oPeople.Take(5)`? Can you show the relevant code?

Comment: use it as a datasource to a grid or repeater control.

Comment: I tested your code (translated to C#) and had no problem. Does the exception occur even if you just do `Dim result as New List(Of oPerson)` and `result.AddRange(oPeople.Take(5))`?

Comment: `oPeople.Take(5)` is going to return an `IEnumerable(Of oPerson)`. Let me guess: you're calling `ToList` on that? That's going to return an `List(Of oPerson)`, not an `oPeople` object.  What you would need to do is create an `oPeople` object, call its `AddRange` method and pass in the `IEnumerable(Of oPerson)`.

Comment: Oops! Just noticed that @ConnorsFan had already posted basically the same advice.